# UpdateCursor is only updating the first letter from the value of my dictionary

Tags: arcpy, cursor, dictionary

I am using an update cursor to update an attribute field with the value of my dictionary.  Both the field and the value are strings.  I am confused why the update cursor is only updating the field with one character from the value of the dictionary. I am stuck and haven't been able to figure it out.

```py
arcpy.env.workspace = r'\\lfkdshome\oit_home\Public\GIS\BWSO\GIS_UNIT\REQUESTS\Bioswales\RainGardentTesting\Bioswales_Archive.gdb'
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

BBL_Dict = {'247849': '3022000054', '664486': '4096010016', '924628': '4112140009'}

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("RG_164", ["BLDG_FID", "BLDG_BBL"]) as cur:
    for join in cur:
        if join[0] in BBL_DICT:
            join[1] = BBL_DICT[join[0]][0]
            cur.updateRow(join)
```

[image]

Comment: It's only using the first character because that's what you asked it to do.  If you try some print statements to debug your code, you'll see this is the case.

Comment: I did do that in print statements.  I just don't understand were in the code it's telling me to do that. Thank You!

Comment: `BBL_DICT[join[0]]` is a string.  `BBL_DICT[join[0]][0]` is a character (the first character in the dictionary lookup)

Comment: Thank You so much I just solved it.  I am new to coding so I miss and often don't understand simple things.

Comment: @Vince Please consider adding your comment as an answer so we can consider this question resolved.

Comment: @Aaron This is a pure Python newbie issue, not anything to do with ArcGIS cursors; I'm not going to Answer after voting to close.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. This post should remain open. I see this as related to cursors, which, as you know, is a primary way to interact with feature attributes in the Esri realm.